# How to convert multiple columns in a list separately in R

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame like this

```
colour  flower  fish
Yellow  Y       W
Blue    N       N
Red     Y       W
```

I want to get a list like this

```
$colour
[1] "Yellow" "Blue" "Red"
$flower
[1] "Y" "N" "Y"
$fish
[1] "W" "N" "W"
```

I have used split as follows, but it does not work for me

```
split(df,row(df)[,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` and the subset operator: `[`

```
lapply(df, `[`)

$colour
[1] "Yellow" "Blue"   "Red"   

$flower
[1] "Y" "N" "Y"

$fish
[1] "W" "N" "W"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `as.list()`...

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~"colour",~"flower", ~"fish",
"Yellow", "Y", "W",
"Blue","N","N",
"Red", "T","W")

as.list(df)
#> $colour
#> [1] "Yellow" "Blue"   "Red"   
#> 
#> $flower
#> [1] "Y" "N" "T"
#> 
#> $fish
#> [1] "W" "N" "W"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unclass` as `data.frame/data.table/tibble` etc are all `list` with some `class` attributes.  By doing `unclass`, remove those attributes to return the `list`

```
unclass(df1)
$colour
[1] "Yellow" "Blue"   "Red"   

$flower
[1] "Y" "N" "Y"

$fish
[1] "W" "N" "W"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(colour = c("Yellow", "Blue", "Red"), flower = c("Y", 
"N", "Y"), fish = c("W", "N", "W")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```